# how to style a single character in bootstrap-vue label

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, label, bootstrap-vue

I can't figure it out, how to style a single character in the bootstrap-vue label:

```html
<b-form-group 
  class="text-left"
  label-cols="4" 
  label-cols-lg="3" 
  label="Name*:" <--- how to style the single * ?
 >
  <b-form-input
    v-model="inputName" 
    placeholder="Name"
  />
</b-form-group>
```

I've tried using template strings but can't get anywhere.

Do you have any ideas on how I can colorize the individual star `*`?

---

I am using `"bootstrap-vue": "2.14.0"` and `"vue": "2.6.10"`

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `label` slot :

```
<b-form-group 
  class="text-left"
  label-cols="4" 
  label-cols-lg="3" 

 >
  <template #label>
     Name <span style="color:red">*</span> :
  </template>
  <b-form-input
    v-model="inputName" 
    placeholder="Name"
  />
</b-form-group>
```